# Problem with turning off display_errors (PHP)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

I set display_errors to Off through my htaccess via [this method](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/14/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/), and it shows that way when I run phpinfo() (display_errors is Off in Local Value and Master Value columns).  Additionally, when I `echo ini_get('display_errors');` in a test script, I get 0 returned.

However, when I trigger an error as follows in one of my scripts:

```
trigger_error("An error", E_USER_WARNING);
```

I DO NOT, however, get an error when running this script which instead writes to the log:

```
$foo = array();
$bar = $foo['does_not_exist'];
```

I'd like it only to write to the error log, not display it as it does.  What's the deal?

**Added background**: I'm on Rackspace Cloud Site hosting, where they don't let you edit a php ini, but you can set basically everything just fine through php_flags in the .htaccess.

Comment: Check your setting again. It's "on".

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Col -- No, phpinfo() says its off. I'm going to add some background info which I left out.  Moses I will try just writing an error handler if all else fails

Comment: I've seen a good post about theses boolean values set in apache files (like .haccess), nobody never known if it's true, 0, or on. Well in fact sometimes it works, sometime it doesn't :-) http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/how-retrieve-boolean-values-php-s-configuration

Comment: I'm having same problem. `trigger_error` seems to ignore display_errors directive. Setting `display_errors` to `0` and calling an inexistent function to trigger an error, it does not show any error as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.. realized that one of my includes which I wasn't using on test pages was the cause of display_errors being set to 1 dynamically.  Col. Shrapnel was write to be skeptical (upvoted his comments)

Answer (score -1):

First, verify that display_errors is really off just before the `trigger_error()` using `ini_get('display_errors');`

It could be getting overridden at run time.

Then, perhaps `trigger_error()` itself is an issue.  Try doing something that would normally trigger an error.  Example:

```
$foo = array();
$bar = $foo['does_not_exist'];
```

If that works as expected, than this issue is definitely `trigger_error()`.

Use `error_log()` instead.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: trigger_error() itself is NOT an issue. and error_log has nothing to do here.

Comment: I ran ini_get('display_errors') and got 0.  And your script does NOT give an error

Comment: So, my first comment to do an `ini_get('display_errors')` was the correct thing to do.  Can you please not down vote since that is the correct thing to do?